# Which would be safe to store authentication token, rootScope or sessionStorage in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, security

I am developing one application based on AngularJS and that will interact with one RESTful service. After authentication from service that returns one token. I need to store token and intercept in every request. I want to understand which would be better to store the token, either rootScope or sessionStorage?

Comment: I do not think one of them is more safe than the other. You can in the JS console print the rootscope and you can in your session see all the stored material. But I suggest sessionStorage for storing the token because the token will be gone on refresh. This guy shows how to store a token in localStorage: https://thinkster.io/angularjs-jwt-auth

Comment: Storage is better because when the app refreshes, the token will no longer exist.  There's also cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $rootScope is a variable that will be gone on page refresh. Therefore would I suggest you use either a cookie or sessionStorage.

SessionStorage will be gone when the user closes his/hers browser tab. If that is not the prefered case then use a cookie.

To add a default header authenticator to your $http requests use an interceptor that you can find documentation about here:

[Interceptor documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

The code for the interceptor would look something like:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $cookies) {
    return {
     'request': function(config) {

          config.headers['Token'] = $cookies.loginTokenCookie;
          return config;
      }
    };
  });
```

Also take a look at the documentation for the angular $cookie service here:

[Cookie documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)

Answer (score 0):

$rootScope and session storage are designed for two different roles. $rootScope is simply a JavaScript variable that makes values accessible application-wide. Session storage is a web browser feature which allows you to persist data beyond page refreshes, or while the session is otherwise maintained. Storing values on $rootScope is nothing more than storing a value in a JavaScript variable; if you refresh the page the value is gone. What you want is either session storage or a cookie, so that your token is persisted beyond page refreshes.

Take a look at [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)